# Android layout_marginTop on different screens

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to create buttons like in the picture. I set second `LinearLayout`'s `marginTop` param `-28dp` to move layout up. And here I get a problem: on **5''** screen it's seems all right *(like on left pic)* but in **7''+**  buttons became bigger (as I want) but it's looks like on the right pic (bottom button moved down). How to solve my problem so that on different screens, it will look the same?
[image]

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/btn_group_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/home_btn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/menu_btn" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/info_btn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/menu_btn" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/btn_group_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="-28dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/kpi_map_btn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/menu_btn" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This layout

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

         <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/hexa" />

        <ImageView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/hexa" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:src="@drawable/hexa" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this is what exactly you need.
Note: Replace my image with yours.

Comment: Try and let me know. You just need to adjust by giving marginTop for the third image once and it will adjust for all devices.

Comment: The fact is that I give small example. There are a lot of buttons which placed in this way. Every LinearLayout (btn_group#) have max 2 btns. I was trying to set marginTop, But it's work the same but in a different side.

Comment: I think it's because screens have different dpi and I dont know how to solve this problem (

Comment: Ok, I find solution. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers I must to create value folder for 7''+ screens

Comment: Sorry for not responding back to you.. And thats gud you got an answer of your own.